# How to Focus on One thing at a time?

Tags: consciousness, attention, concentration

My Mind is always filled with useless some many thoughts at a single moment, that i feel hard to focus , concentrate my attention on one task at a time. My attention span is very low. I get distracted very easily and that's the reason i feel for my average life with a mediocre results.

please suggest me some techniques/methods which will surely increase focus power.

Comment: This is exactly what is going on my mind ... I have the same problem too. ! I hope someone answer it very quickly